# Android Studio Firebase How To Insert A Long List In Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert a long list of products in real time database using the following code. The list has about 90 products, but when I try to add them I am getting a few products less, like 2-3 products are missing. Is there any way to insert all products? I believe I am getting less products because I am using timestamp.

Here is my code

```html
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
String[] productTitles = {length of array is 93};
String[] productQuantities = {length of array is 93};
String[] productIcons = {length of array is 93};
String[] productCategories = {length of array is 93};

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put("discountAvailable","false");
        hashMap.put("discountNote","");
        hashMap.put("discountPrice","0");
        hashMap.put("isAvailable","Available");
        hashMap.put("isApproved","Approved");
        hashMap.put("productType","Default");
        hashMap.put("originalPrice","");
        hashMap.put("productDescription", "");
        hashMap.put("uid",""+firebaseAuth.getUid());
        String timestamp;
        for (int i = 0; i < productTitles.length; i++) {
            timestamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis()+1;
            hashMap.put("timestamp", "" + timestamp);
            hashMap.put("productTitle", "" + productTitles[i]);
            hashMap.put("productCategory", "" + productCategories[i]);
            hashMap.put("productQuantity","" + productQuantities[i]);
            hashMap.put("productIcon",""+productIcons[i]);
            hashMap.put("productId",""+timestamp);
            reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Products").child(timestamp).setValue(hashMap);

        }
```

Comment: Do you get any error for those 2-3 missing products?

Comment: No i am not getting any error, some random products are simply missing, no issue with any other product

Answer (score 0):

You can replaced the timestap with a firebase key.

```
for (int i = 0; i < productTitles.length; i++) {
        timestamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis()+1;
        hashMap.put("timestamp", "" + timestamp);
        hashMap.put("productTitle", "" + productTitles[i]);
        hashMap.put("productCategory", "" + productCategories[i]);
        hashMap.put("productQuantity","" + productQuantities[i]);
        hashMap.put("productIcon",""+productIcons[i]);
        hashMap.put("productId",""+timestamp);
        String uniqueID = reference.push().getKey();
        reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Products")
        .child(uniqueID).setValue(hashMap);

    }
```

I am not sure if this works or not.